# Upload files with AJAX and Zend Framework

Tags: php, ajax, zend-framework

I'm trying to send an .xml file for PHP to read.

PHP (ZEND_FRAMEWORK):

```
$data = array(file => $this->_request->getParam("form-file"));
$_result = $this->insert($data);
```

JS:

```
$.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: 'url',
      cache: false,
      contentType: 'multipart/form-data',
      processData: false,
      data: form.serialize()
}).success(function () { 
      alert('success');       
}).fail(function () {
      alert('fail');
});
```

Comment: Try and use English next time :) do you have an error? More information is needed

Comment: I have problem in receiving with ZEND, but I consiencia on:

file_get_contents($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'])